# Accessing perl subroutine from different perl script

Tags: perl

I had 1 perl script in which we write couple of subroutines. Example:

```
# Try_1.pl

main();

sub main{
---
---
 check();
}

check {
--
--}
```

Now, i wrote another script `Try_2.pl`, in which i want to call check subroutine of perl script `Try_1.pl`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It sounds like you want to create a module.  Try_1.pm (**Edit:** note extension) should have the following form:

```
package Try_1;
use base 'Exporter';
our @EXPORT = qw(check);

sub check {
}

1;
```

And then Try_2.pl needs to get that code:

```
use Try_1 qw(check);
```

That what you're looking for?

Comment: Also the file containing this package will need to be named `Try_1.pm` and placed in your `@INC` path.

Comment: further, since you use `@EXPORT` you do not need to explicitly import the function `check` in Try_2.pl, a simple `use Try_1` will work. You may use `@EXPORT_OK` to require an explicit import.

Comment: @Joel Sure, you don't *need* to specify the function, but it's good practice to only import the functions you need.  If you specify particular functions explicitly, it does not import anything else.  It also tells you up at the top of your code just how much your global namespace is being polluted (since you're calling them out explicitly, it's arguably not being 'polluted' at all).

Comment: Is it possible to make variables global, across the main script and also the modules that you create? If so, how would it be done as I am having some trouble? thanks a lot

Comment: @perl-user That's a different question - you should search SE and then if you don't find the answer you should ask it as a question.

Answer (score 5):

If you are not using modules (extension `.pm`) but instead use libraries (extension `.pl`):

```
require 'Try_1.pl';
check();
```

Make sure that both files `Try_1.pl` and `Try_2.pl` are in the same directory.

Answer (score 1):

You  may need this

test1.pl:

```
use Routines;
{    
    my $hello = "hello123";
    hello( $hello );    
    # ...
}
```

test2.pl:

```
package Routines;
sub hello 
{
    my $hello = shift;
    print "$hello\n";
}
1;
```

Answer (score 0):

"run"'s answer tested work, but need to call like "Try_1::check()". Otherwise show error "Undefined subroutine &main::check()".